# How can I render a list conditionally with v-for by evaluating one of the iteration values to a computed value?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I want to render a list of tiles/links populated by a list of dicts from data. However I only want the them to be rendered if the access_level (a key in the list) to a computed value from the vuex store. Can you please help with the best way to do this?

I have tried combining a v-if and a v-for in the same element but I have found out that this is not possible. I tried calling a function as well as using the logic within the element.

I have tried this:

```
<v-list>
  <v-list-tile v-for="link in userLinks" :key="link" :to="link.to" :v-if="link.access >= accessLevel">
    <v-list-tile-action>
      <v-icon class="primary--text">
        {{ link.icon }}
      </v-icon>
    </v-list-tile-action>
    <v-list-tile-content>
      <v-list-tile-title class="primary--text">
        {{ link.text }}
      </v-list-tile-title>
    </v-list-tile-content>
  </v-list-tile>
</v-list>
```

```
data() {
  return {
    userLinks: [
      { icon: 'security', text: 'Admin Panel', to: '/admin', access: 4 },
      { icon: 'account_circle', text: 'Profile', to: '/user', access: 1 }
    ]
  }
},
computed: {
  accessLevel() {
    return this.$store.state.authentication.access_level
  }
},
```

and this:

```
<v-list>
  <v-list-tile v-for="link in userLinks" :key="link" :to="link.to" :v-if="accessCheck(link.access)">
    <v-list-tile-action>
      <v-icon class="primary--text">
        {{ link.icon }}
      </v-icon>
    </v-list-tile-action>
    <v-list-tile-content>
      <v-list-tile-title class="primary--text">
        {{ link.text }}
      </v-list-tile-title>
    </v-list-tile-content>
  </v-list-tile>
</v-list>
```

```
data() {
  return {
    userLinks: [
      { icon: 'security', text: 'Admin Panel', to: '/admin', access: 4 },
      { icon: 'account_circle', text: 'Profile', to: '/user', access: 1 }
    ]
  }
},
computed: {
  accessLevel() {
    return this.$store.state.authentication.access_level
  }
},
methods: {
  accessCheck(level) {
    return level >= this.accessLevel ? true : false
  }
}
```

Component template:

```
<template>
  <nav>
    <v-toolbar flat app>
      <v-toolbar-side-icon class="grey--text" @click="drawer = !drawer" />
      <v-spacer />
      <v-menu left offset-y :nudge-width="200" class="mr-3">
        <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
          <v-icon x-large class="primary--text" v-on="on">
            account_circle
          </v-icon>
        </template>
        <v-card>
          <v-list>
            <v-list-tile v-for="link in userLinks" :key="link.id" :to="link.to" :v-if="accessCheck(link.access)">
              <v-list-tile-action>
                <v-icon class="primary--text">
                  {{ link.icon }}
                </v-icon>
              </v-list-tile-action>
              <v-list-tile-content>
                <v-list-tile-title class="primary--text">
                  {{ link.text }}
                </v-list-tile-title>
              </v-list-tile-content>
            </v-list-tile>
            <v-list-tile @click="logout">
              <v-list-tile-action>
                <v-icon class="primary--text">
                  power_settings_new
                </v-icon>
              </v-list-tile-action>
              <v-list-tile-content>
                <v-list-tile-title class="primary--text">
                  Logout
                </v-list-tile-title>
              </v-list-tile-content>
            </v-list-tile>
          </v-list>
        </v-card>
      </v-menu>
    </v-toolbar>
    <v-navigation-drawer v-model="drawer" app class="primary">
      <v-layout column align-center>
        <v-flex class="mt-5 mb-4">
          <v-avatar size="200">
            <img src="culogo.png">
          </v-avatar>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
      <v-list>
        <v-list-tile v-for="link in navLinks" :key="link" :to="link.to">
          <v-list-tile-action>
            <v-icon class="white--text">
              {{ link.icon }}
            </v-icon>
          </v-list-tile-action>
          <v-list-tile-content>
            <v-list-tile-title class="white--text">
              {{ link.text }}
            </v-list-tile-title>
          </v-list-tile-content>
        </v-list-tile>
      </v-list>
    </v-navigation-drawer>
  </nav>
</template>
```

I would like the tiles to be rendered only if the user access level is greater of equal to the required access level specified in the list.

I am using nuxt.js

Thank you.

Comment: Use `v-if` instead of `:v-if`. You also shouldn't use a `v-if` and `v-for` on the same element https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-if-with-v-for

Comment: can you help with another way i can acheive what i am trying to do please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it solves your problem?

```
<v-list>
    <v-list-tile v-for="link in userLinks" :key="link" :to="link.to" v-if="accessCheck(link.access)">
        <v-list-tile-action>
            <v-icon class="primary--text">
                {{ link.icon }}
            </v-icon>
        </v-list-tile-action>
        <v-list-tile-content>
            <v-list-tile-title class="primary--text"> 
                {{ link.text }}
            </v-list-tile-title>
        </v-list-tile-content>
    </v-list-tile>
</v-list>



computed: {
    // Add parameters to computed property this way
    accessCheck() {
        return (level) => {
            return this.$store.state.authentication.access_level >= level;
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit 1:**

And more elegant solution if you declare **getters** in store. Not the best practice to access the store's state in components!

**store.js**:

```
getters: {
    getAccessLevel(state){
        return state.authentication.access_level;
    }
}
```

**component:**

```
computed: {
    // Add parameters to computed property this way
    accessCheck() {
        return (level) => {
            return this.$store.getters['getAccessLevel'] >= level;
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit 2:**

Your condition is not valid!!

> I would like the tiles to be rendered only if the user access level is greater of equal to the required access level specified in the list.
>   `return level >= this.accessLevel ? true : false`

The right condition:

`return level <= this.accessLevel`

Comment: Thank you. I am now getting the following warnings for my loop: 

```Avoid using non-primitive value as key, use string/number value instead```
```Duplicate keys detected: '[object Object]'. This may cause an update error```

I have tried adding an id key to my list and setting the key to `:key="link.id"` but still the same errors.

Comment: i appreciate the help

Comment: In your userLinks array I don't see id for the link objects. 
Try this:

`<v-list-tile v-for="(link, index) in userLinks" :key="'list-tile-' + index" :to="link.to" v-if="accessCheck(link.access)"> `

Does this solves your error?

Comment: i added the id key after to try to get it working. i have tried what you have suggested and i am still having the same problem.

Comment: It's strange. This is your whole template in the component? Don't you render the `<v-list>` twice? Because it's a unique key. Can you please paste your whole component's template?

Comment: It's throwing the error for your second `<v-list-tile>` v-for cycle. `<v-list-tile v-for="(link, index) in navLinks" :key="'nav-link-' + index" :to="link.to">`

Comment: thank you, that has removed the error. i did not realise that the key would clash in 2 different loops.

Comment: ```accessCheck() {
   return (level) => {
      console.log('user level: ' + this.$store.getters['authentication/getAccessLevel'])
      console.log('access level: ' + level)
      console.log('access expresion: ' + (this.$store.getters['authentication/getAccessLevel'] >= level))
      return (this.$store.getters['authentication/getAccessLevel'] >= level)
  }
}```

the console logs return the correct data though

Comment: i have managed to get it working, by turning of vue/no-use-v-if-with-v-for in eslinting

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Glad to hear to got it working. You are welcome!